# Can't stop form closing when background worker is in progress

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form with a background worker in a c# winforms application (Visual Studio 2010, .net 4). When the background worker is busy I would like to warn the user aboout it when tries to close the form and cancel form closing. I'd like to handle it in form closing event by setting form close cancellation to true.

BUT it still closes the form!

Here is the code snippet I use:

```
private void FormDrivenDistance_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (myBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
  {
     Messenger.ShowCriticalMessage("Don't close, in progress!");
                    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

Where is the bug?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `myBackgroundWorker.IsBusy` returns `true`?  Have you tried setting a break point inside the check to make sure it's being called?

Are you sure that the event is hooked up properly?

If those things are true, the bug would have to be in some other part of the code.

There may also be some other handler on `FormClosing` setting `Cancel` to `false`, but that's probably a less likely scenario.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, everything works fine except this and isbusy returns true. Yes, event is hooked up properly.

Comment: @Tamas what happens when you set a breakpoint on `e.Cancel = true;` and step through the code?

Comment: It simply closes the form, even if cancel is set to true. All in all I found the reason of the bug: I use an open source UI component to create Visual Studio like IDE (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/VS_IDE_Dock_Container.aspx), and as I see now it causes the problem, it makes some tricks with form closing in the background and does not use cancel in a correct way... Sad news for me, I need this component and also cancellation... Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @Tamas Does it work if you remove the `Messenger.ShowCriticalMessage` line?  Unless something funky goes on in that method, it should work if what you say is true.

Comment: You know you can just use the VS Shell itself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb510103.aspx (isolated mode)

Comment: So, if I use a 'normal' Windows form - not this dock container form - the code works properly, it cancels form closing. The root of the problem is this dockable form I wrote about in my previous post.

Comment: @Tamas that code project article does mention how you should prevent their forms from closing if you search for "Preventing the close of a form" on that page.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks Davy, I implemented it, now it works! :) Not a nice solution, but works at least.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move e.Cancel before your message?

Note that if you're trying to prevent the race condition and stop the InvalidOperationException caused when the form closes before the worker completes, it doesn't 100% do so; you might close it in the interval between the completion itself (InProgress is now false) and the callback (OnWorkerCompleted).  You still need to handle the exception either way.

Since you have to handle it either way, you may as well just let the user close the form.  It's a nuisance for the user to have to wait for something to complete that they don't care about.

Comment: Thx for your answer but it sounds really terrible for me. I would like to cancel form closing only, nothing more it. Should not be so tricky. It is like hunting for a pigeon with an F14 Tomcat...Anyway, thanks your help! ;)